# IOS: UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uitableview

In my project I would create a table view with 10 row, but these 10 rows must be UITableViewCell customizable. Do you suggest links where I can find some suggest code?

Comment: What do you mean by customizable? Just a subclass of UITableViewCell containing something else than the template cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) has three different approaches: Programmatically Adding Subviews to a Cell’s Content View, Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files and Subclassing UITableViewCell.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) as well.